# How to add Seoul dataset in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery I want to add a dataset in Seoul (asia-northeast3) but I can't find it in the list of locations (I only see Mumbai, Singapore, Hong Kong, Taiwan, and Tokyo)

however the big query documentation states that there is such a location

How can I add a dataset in Seoul?

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very bizarre, I've just check it out on my console and I can confirm that it exist a bit in the bottom between `europ-west4` and `us-west3`.

Anyway, in case you weren't able to get it on the list, you can still create it using the command line on the console with :

`bq --location=asia-northeast3 mk --dataset <project_id>:my_dataset`

Comment: this is the accepted answer. I still can't see Seoul in the dropdown list, but the command line worked like a charm